# Java Regular Expression to match any method signature

Tags: java, regex

I need to find any kind of Java method signature in a string using regular expression. This is what I have so far an it is not very pretty. The last piece I need help with is implementing case7, Matching method with more than one parameter and also make the regex more concise and readable.

```
 import java.util.regex.Matcher;
    import java.util.regex.Pattern;

    class MethodMatcher {

public static void main(String[] args) {

    String PARAM_ARG_PATTERN
            = Pattern.quote("(") + 
            "(([\\s]*[a-zA-Z_][\\w\\d]*[\\s]*[a-zA-Z_][\\w\\d]*[\\s]*)|[\\s]*)" 
            + Pattern.quote(")");

    String METHOD_NAME_PATTERN = "[\\s]+[a-zA-Z_][\\w\\d]+[\\s]*";

    String METHOD_PATTERN = METHOD_NAME_PATTERN + PARAM_ARG_PATTERN;

    String case1 = " _validName__ ( _TypeName _variable)";
    String case2 = " 7invalidName (_TypeName variable)";
    String case3 = "badName_ (_pp8p_7 _s5de)";   //method Name has no leading space
    String case4 = " Valid4Name_()";                 //No Parameter ValidName( )
    String case5 = " validName(7BadType variable)";
    String case6 = " validName_(InvalidParam)";     //no variable name
    String case7 = " validName(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2)"; //but fails need help implementing

    String cases[] = {case1, case2, case3, case4, case5, case6, case7};
    int c = 1;
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile(METHOD_PATTERN);

    for (String strMethod : cases) {
        Matcher m = p.matcher(strMethod);
        if (m.find())
            System.out.println(strMethod + " passed");
        c++;
    }

}
```

}

Comment: Don't try it. You're using the wrong tool for this job. You need a parser. You'll come up with an RE that kinda works, and you will keep finding exceptions to that and having to tweak it. Forever. It will never be right. It can't be.

Comment: What about annotations? Generic types? Comments? Do you want to handle them ?

Comment: No only method signature (name, parameter )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This looks more like homework or finger exercise than an actual project. Here is a jumpstart:

```
^\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\s*(?:\(|\G)(\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\s+([a-zA-Z_]\w+),?)*\)\s*$
```

Update: The following pattern allows unlimited `args` (the anchors IMHO not needed):

```
^\s*(?:^\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\s*\(\s*|\G,\s*)(\s*([a-zA-Z_]\w+)\s+([a-zA-Z_]\w+),?)*\)\s*$
```

Original demo code:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

public class T
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {

        final String regex = "^\\s*\n" 
                            + "([a-zA-Z_]\\w+)                                    # function name\n" 
                            + "\\s*\n" 
                            + "(?:\\(|\\G)\n" 
                            + "(\\s*([a-zA-Z_]\\w+)\\s+([a-zA-Z_]\\w+),?)*           #args\n" 
                            + "\\)\n" 
                            + "\\s*$";

        final String string = " _validName__ ( _TypeName _variable)\n" 
                            + " 7invalidName (_TypeName variable)\n" 
                            + "badName_ (_pp8p_7 _s5de)\n" 
                            + " Valid4Name_()\n" 
                            + " validName(7BadType variable)\n" 
                            + " validName_(InvalidParam)\n" 
                            + " validName(Type1 arg1, Type2 arg2)";

        final Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex, Pattern.COMMENTS | Pattern.MULTILINE);
        final Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(string);

        while (matcher.find()) {
            System.out.println("Full match: " + matcher.group(0));
            for (int i = 1; i <= matcher.groupCount(); i++) {
                System.out.println("Group " + i + ": " + matcher.group(i));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**[Updated Demo](https://regex101.com/r/MYmgXw/2)**

Comment: What about (1) arrays, (2) multidimensional arrays, (3) qualified types, (4) generics, all the above as (5) return values and (6) parameter types; (7) varargs, (8) ...

Comment: @wp78de this is for a personal project i'm working on. product owner refuses parsers

Comment: @wp78de, Attempting to reconcile the updated regular expression shown just above the thread with your Java demonstration, and I see that it begins with "^\s*(?:^\s*" while the expression in your code begins with "^\s*" - omitting the second subexpression "(?:^\s*" that seems to me does nothing.

Comment: On closer inspection, the expression appears to be capturing the last parameter only. This isn't fatal, but it did confuse me for quite a while.

Comment: @DavidA.Gray Yes, this is correct. The pattern as is is most useful for validation or extraction purpose - but nor parsing. I would design it differently now.